# Keras - python - Custom CallBack - sample_weight

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

I want to get the **sample_weight** values in a keras custom call back.
I cannot find documentation on it.
The documentation, I found, is on how to retrieve the weight of the model, but not the **sample_weight**.

Anyone, already did it ?

Thanks for the help,

regards,

Alexandre

Comment: The callback receives the training logs (loss / metrics) and not the training data.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreDurand, you can use the get_weights() method to extract the weights of the model. This function returns both trainable and non-trainable weight values associated with the layers as a list of NumPy arrays. Thank You.